# Official OpenID icons for Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-openid

For those of us who create plugins for other systems that use OpenID, it would surely be nice to have some shiny Stack Exchange icons to use in OpenID selector menus. I'm not sure that this is possible with the logo being trademarked, however.

To be clear, I'm talking about icons like these:

[image: OpenID Logos]

Would it be possible to make some available? I'd really like to add it to the OpenID menu I use on most of my Wordpress sites. If not the 'official' logo, perhaps some created just for purposes like this? Perhaps with the OpenID symbol in it?

It would be neat if people who visit our sites from our profiles see the familiar icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure try

https://stackexchange.com/about/logos

There is also

https://openid.stackexchange.com/

and

https://openid.stackexchange.com/content/img/sprites.png

[image]

Comment: Do we have an icon only version?